# Error in missing value imputation using MICE package

Tags: r, missing-data, r-mice, imputation

I have a huge data `(4M x 17)` that has missing values. Two columns are categorical, rest all are numerical. I want to use MICE package for missing value imputation. This is what I tried:

```
> testMice <- mice(myData[1:100000,]) # runs fine  
> testTot <- predict(testMice, myData)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "mids"
```

Running the imputation on whole dataset was computationally expensive, so I ran it on only the first 100K observations. Then I am trying to use the output to impute the whole data.

Is there anything wrong with my approach? If yes, what should I do to make it correct? If no, then why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `mice` nor `hmisc` provide the parameter estimates from the imputation process. Both `Amelia` and `imputeMulti` do. In both cases, you can extract the parameter estimates and use them for imputing your other observations.

- `Amelia` assumes your data are distributed as a multivariate normal (eg. X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma).
- `imputeMulti` assumes that your data is distributed as a multivariate multinomial distribution. That is the complete cell counts are distributed (X \sim M(n,\theta)) where n is the number of observations.

Fitting can be done as follows, via example data. Examining parameter estimates is shown further below.

```
library(Amelia)
library(imputeMulti)
data(tract2221, package= "imputeMulti")
test_dat2 <- tract2221[, c("gender", "marital_status","edu_attain", "emp_status")]
# fitting
IM_EM <- multinomial_impute(test_dat2, "EM",conj_prior = "non.informative", verbose= TRUE)
amelia_EM <- amelia(test_dat2, m= 1, noms= c("gender", "marital_status","edu_attain", "emp_status"))
```

- The parameter estimates from the `amelia` function are found in `amelia_EM$mu` and `amelia_EM$theta`.
- The parameter estimates in `imputeMulti` are found in `IM_EM@mle_x_y` and can be accessed via the `get_parameters` method.

`imputeMulti` has noticeably higher imputation accuracy for categorical data relative to either of the other 3 packages, though it only accepts multinomial (eg. `factor`) data.

All of this information is in the **currently unpublished** vignette for `imputeMulti`. The paper has been submitted to JSS and I am awaiting a response before adding the vignette to the package.

Comment: A very poor answer IMHO. Good luck trying to use a high quality `Amelia` model with data of this size. BTW using a multinomial model is well described by the comment I already made, it's essentially a GLM with a multinomial distribution as you would find with `multinom` or `mlogit`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `predict()` with `mice`. It's not a model you're fitting per se. Your imputed results are already there for the 100,000 rows.

If you want data for all rows then you have to put all rows in `mice`. I wouldn't recommend it though, unless you set it up on a large cluster with dozens of CPU cores.

Comment: Are there any packages that would do something like what I am trying to do?

Comment: @SonuMishra Well what you can do is to go ahead and fit a statistical model with something like `glm` or a random forest then use that to predict the missing values. Or just use mean imputation, which is much faster. You can use the `RRF` package's function `na.roughfix` for that.

Comment: @hack-R those are very poor suggestions in my opinion. `mice` uses EM which is **vastly** superior imputation strategy than GLM. That is, unless you meant an iterative algorithm via GLM that converges to a solution; but that is not much different from EM.

Comment: @Alex Well, I'm sorry you feel that way, perhaps it's guided by ignorance and inexperience. First of all you're comparing something which is a practical alternative against something which is not an option do to computational resource requirements. Secondly you're making a strong claim with nothing to back it up.